# Error no se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'string' en 'bool'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Quiero hacer un una casilla de verificacion con la clase Toggle, pero me envia un mensaje de error, como lograr solucionar eso, aqui mi codigo

```html
<div class="editor-label toggle">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.luz3, "lampara tres")

      @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.luz3, new { @type = "checkbox"})
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.luz3)
  <i data-swchon-text="SI" data-swchoff-text="NO"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿que tipo de dato es `luz3`?

Comment: Es tipo varchar, pero con solo dos valores (2byte) verdareo y falso

Comment: Pero en la clase de C#

Comment: en la clase es un string

Comment: Ese es tu problema, ahí te deje una respuesta, decime si quedan claras las posibles soluciones

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema es lógico, se da porque la propiedad `luz3` es de tipo `string`, ya que según la **[documentación de Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee830434(v=vs.118).aspx)** de

```
public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxFor<TModel>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> expression,
    ....
)
```

No puede recibir como expresión lambda un parámetro de un tipo que no sea `bool`

Para solucionar tu problema tenes dos opciones:

1. Redefinir tu clase, para que la propiedad `luz3` sea de tipo `bool`
2. Crear un EditorTemplate personalizado, con la lógica necesaria para poder utilizar `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.luz3)` en tu vista (si te interesa esto, te recomiendo que leas [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6861314/5213794))
3. Una tercer opción puede ser la de utilizar `Html.CheckBox()` en lugar de `Html.CheckBoxFor()`, si bien es poco legible, es una opción, podría hacerse de la siguiente manera

   ```
   @Html.CheckBox(
               Html.NameFor(x => x.luz3).ToString(),
               Model.luz3 == "Verdadero" ? true : false,
               new { @id = Html.IdFor(x => x.luz3).ToString() })
   ```

   De esta manera, si `luz3` vale `Verdadero` el checkbox estará chequeado, modo contrario no lo estará, y tendrá el `name` e `id` que generaría `Html.CheckBoxFor()` para recibir el modelo en tu Controller de manera apropiada

Tras nombrarte las 3 alternativas (que se me ocurren a mi, al menos) te recomiendo, que elijas la primera.

Comment: Carezco de información, apenas soy nuevo en esto de c#, pero puedo decir que la primera me valdría bien, aunque re-definir la clase, para que la propiedad luz3 sea del tipo bool, estoy pensando en que talvez pueda declararlo como si fuera un bool utilizando un ConvertTo.

Comment: Otra opción, sería la de hacer tu método `luz3` privado, y hacer una propiedad pública, al más estilo `public Luz3 { get { return luz3 == "True" }}` de modo que te devuelva un `bool` con `true/false`